# Word for foundation patches

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Sometimes when you put powder on your face after applying a foundation it leaves white patches due to heavy sweating.What are such patches called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Blotch"

> an irregular spot or discoloration, esp a dark and relatively large one such as an ink stain

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blotch